# Line not grepped even if present

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, grep, line

I am using following code to grep the values that meet the conditions as specified below in the code.The line to be grepped should meet either criteria of having the 2nd column -1 value present in the file or 3rd column+1 value to be present.

```
 while read intron ; do
 start=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print ($2-1)}')
 end=$(grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print ($3+1)}')
  if (grep  $start ../file_to_be_grepped_from | grep -q :E) && (grep $end ../file_to_be_grepped_from | grep -q :E) ; then
    grep -w $intron ../file_to_be_grepped_from
  fi 
 done <  another_file
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
 grep: 46844233: No such file or directory
 grep: 46844359: No such file or directory
 grep: 40174126: No such file or directory
 grep: 40174403: No such file or directory
 grep: 40176362: No such file or directory
 grep: 40174671: No such file or directory
 grep: 31542739: No such file or directory
```

Out of which most of the values are not present in the file, except for 40174403 and 40174671. The lines that should be grepped (and are present) but which are not look like this:

```
  chr19 40174127    40174403    ENSG00000226025:E4  +
  chr19 40174671    40174788    ENSG00000226025:E5  +
```

Any suggestions in correcting and improving the code would be welcome. 
My input looks something like this:

```
ENSG00000225518:I2
ENSG00000225535:I1
ENSG00000225535:I2
ENSG00000225535:I3
ENSG00000226025:I4
```

and the expected output is

```
chr1    226274755   226277190   ENSG00000225518:I2  + 
chr7    114719164   114758265   ENSG00000225535:I1  +
chr7    114758880   114758988   ENSG00000225535:I2  +
chr7    114759111   114762231   ENSG00000225535:I3  +
chr19   40174404    40174670    ENSG00000226025:I4  +
```

Comment: Show input and expected output, there can even more simple way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm amazed that any of the values are present as you `print ($2-1)` and `print ($3+1)`.

Comment: actually it did work for many lines, I hope that's not the problem.

Comment: Can't really say since there is no source data and expected output.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: The grep error messages are clear. And the mistake in your code is about the lack of double quotes in most of your grep commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in order to prevent the grep error messages, you can correct your code by surrounding the multiple `$var` expansion by double quotes:

```
while read intron ; do
  start=$(grep -w "$intron" ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print ($2-1)}')
  end=$(grep -w "$intron" ../file_to_be_grepped_from | awk '{print ($3+1)}')
  if   (grep "$start" ../file_to_be_grepped_from | grep -q :E) &&
       (grep "$end" ../file_to_be_grepped_from | grep -q :E)
  then
       grep -w "$intron" ../file_to_be_grepped_from
  fi 
done <  another_file
```

The first non-option argument of the grep command is the **pattern** to find. The next arguments are the files to look into. If the variable `intron` contains several values separated by blanks, such as `blablabla 46844233 46844359`, then `grep -w $intron` is expanded to `grep -w blablabla 46844233 46844359` where `blablabla` is the pattern to find and `46844233`and `46844359` are names of files which `grep` will try to open.